# Correct form for sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

For infinite sequence $a_n = \frac{0}{2^0}, \frac{1}{2^0}, \frac{0}{2^1}, \frac{1}{2^1}, \frac{2}{2^1}, \frac{0}{2^2}, \frac{1}{2^2}, \frac{2}{2^2}, \frac{3}{2^2}, \frac{4}{2^2}, \ldots, \frac{0}{2^n}, \frac{1}{2^n}, \frac{2}{2^n}, \ldots, \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}, \frac{2^n}{2^n}, \dots$

I have tried to capture it in formula:

$$b_k = k \quad \textrm{and} \quad  a_n = \frac{(b_k)\mkern-10.5mu\mathop{\vphantom{)}}\limits_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}}}{2^{n-1}} \quad \textrm{for} \quad {n} \in\mathbb{N}, {k} \in \mathbb{N}_0$$

I suppose that formula is technically ok here (i.e. it outputs the members of sequence specified above), but my question is, is this allowed to write this way? And also if there is more elegant way to write formula for this sequence.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{k=0}^pk=\dfrac {p(p+1)}2$

Comment: @DINEDINE Could you elaborate on that? Let's say I replace p with $2^{n-1}$ I already have there, then I get whole formula: $\frac{\frac{2^{n-1}(2^{n-1} + 1)}{2}}{2^{n-1}}$ but for $n=1$ $a_1 = 1$ instead of $0$. I don't think I can substitute it with this formula from your hint, or I am thinking about it from wrong perspective.

Comment: To clarify In my formula I don't use pure summation, instead I use it as series using summation sign as specified here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)

Comment: Your formula is wrong, @peterparada. With $n=1$ it gives $a_1 = 1$, but it has to be 0.

Comment: @SilentMath with $n = 1$ there is $k_1 = 0$, $k_2 = 1$ as first member of sequence in numerator, which gives $\frac{0}{2^0}$ for $k_1$ and $\frac{1}{2^0}$ for $k_2$. I know formula might be wrong, but don't know how to write it more properly, i.e. for $a_1$ there are $2^0 + 1$ members of sequence, for $a_2$ there are $2^1 + 1$ members of sequence, for $a_3$ there are $2^2 + 1$ members of sequence etc.

Comment: At $n=1$, $\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n-1}} k}{2^{n-1}} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{1} k}{1} = 1/1 = 1.$

Comment: @SilentMath I think I know what you want to show me, what I mean there is separate sequence in numerator for all $k = 0$ to $2^{n-1}$ and also whole fraction for all $n = 1$ to $\infty$. I don't want to use it as sum, just don't know how to properly capture it in formula.

Comment: @SilentMath I've updated formula not using sum, instead using another sequence $b_k$ dependent on $a_n$.

Comment: A nice closed formula might be hard to reach. The issue is that the power on the denominator change every $m=2^n+n-1$, but expressing $n$ in function of $m$ is ugly (LambertW an all), so you cannot hope for something like $\dfrac{u_n}{2^{floor(\log_2(n))}}$...

Comment: Makes me think of Cantor's formula for mapping the rationals (or pairs of integers) to the integers.